# calling values from database to dropdown list, doesn't show all the values

Tags: php

i have a table in my database called categorys, it has two columns cat_id and cat_name ,, i finally managed to get the select right but it doesn't show all of the table rows, there's 22 row it only shows 11 of them ! how can i fix that ?
here's the code i used

```
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM categorys";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    ?>  

    <select name="taskOption">
    <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>>
<?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?>
 </option> <?php } ?>
</select> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you show me the value here from DB from which it is not displayed

Comment: ya give me a sec .. i'll screenshot the table and the output

Comment: @Deee9994 if you do print_r($row), what output do you get? Can you post it in your question too please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change here, missing closing double quote `"`

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>">
```

Comment: happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing quote after your option value. So it takes two times through before it closes the value. Therefore, only half your rows are showing.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM categorys";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>  

<select name="taskOption">
<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?>
</option> <?php } ?>
</select> 
<?php } ?>
```